# How to get browser go back button event and prevented from default behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

with respect to browser default go back button behavior . my app have a special case to ignore it on certain conditions for example .
i have modal if the modal is opened instead of going back just close the modal.
i have no idea if it's possible or not any help

```
function keyEventClose(event){
        var status = $('#myModal').is(':visible');
        if(status){
        //prevent from going back just close the modal
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }else{
        //go back as default 
          window.history.back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: very [elaborately](https://www.irt.org/script/311.htm)

Answer (score 0):

after looking for an hour finally find the solution to this problem . as i did not find a current answer here. so this answer maybe helpful for some one.

```
$('#openfeed').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var stateObj = { foo: "modal-opened" };
    history.pushState(stateObj, "modal-opened", "modal-opened");
})

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  $('#openfeed').modal('hide');
});
```

as you can see when ever the modal is opened we create fake URL in history by  [pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) (browser do not check for URLs created by this function so no reload on the page) when ever browser go back is pressed an [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate)`event is generated after attaching this event to document the problem solved .